# How to see all the possible options for schema metadata in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-transform, tensorflow-data-validation

I am using tensorflow data validation and I am trying to build schemas around my datasets. I've built the initial schemas and I can see/edit them in notepad, but I'm having a hard time actually finding a resource that shows me exactly what kind of parameters I can set in the file for a given data type (ie min or max values or data shapes).

Does anyone know of a good resource or even a comprehensive schema I can use to further edit my schema file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schemas are just a kind of protocol buffers message, and they are defined within [TensorFlow Metadata](https://github.com/tensorflow/metadata). You can find the protocol buffers definition in [`tensorflow_metadata/proto/v0/schema.proto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/metadata/blob/v0.15.0/tensorflow_metadata/proto/v0/schema.proto), which describes and documents all the possible properties and options.